# Showing only values which are larger than the user entered value in C#

Tags: c#

## Question

After finishing this product order manager, I was tasked with adding a feature which lets the user enter a double value, which once entered, will only show the products with prices greater than the chosen value.

I am lost on how I should begin to add this extra option to allow for the filtering of data based on what the user enters.

If someone could point me in the correct direction, I would be ever so thankful!

## ConsoleView.cs

```
class ConsoleView
{
    public int ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("_________Menu________");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Add Orders");
        Console.WriteLine("2) See all orders");
        Console.WriteLine("3) Filter Orders");
        Console.WriteLine("4) exit");
        Console.WriteLine("______________________");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a selection (1-4):");

        return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public Order AddOrder()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the name of the product?");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What is the amount paid for the product?");
        double value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        return new Order(name, value);           
    }

    public void DisplayAllOrders(Order[] orders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("___________ORDERS_____________");
        for (int i = 0; i< orders.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Product Name: " + orders[i].GetOrders() + " - Amount Paid - " + orders[i].GetAmount());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("______________________________");
    }

    public void FilterOrder(Order filter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What numerical value would you like the information to be greater than?");
        double Value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());



    }


}
```

## Order.cs

```
class Order
{

    private string orderName;
    private double orderAmount;

    public Order(string ProductName, double Price)
    {
        SetName(ProductName);
        SetAmount(Price);
    }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        orderName = name;
    }

    public string GetOrders()
    {
        return orderName;
    }

    public void SetAmount(double value)
    {
        orderAmount = value;
    }

    public double GetAmount()
    {
        return orderAmount;
    }

    public static void FilterPrices(double userNum)
    {
        int largeNum = priceArray[0];
    }
}
```

## OrderManager.cs

```
class OrderManager
{
    private List<Order> orders;

    public OrderManager()
    {
        orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    public void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        orders.Add(order);

    }

   public void setAmount(Order amount)
    {
        orders.Add(amount);
    }

    public Order[] GetOrder()
    {
        return orders.ToArray();
    }      
}
```

## Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsoleView view = new ConsoleView();
    OrderManager model = new OrderManager();
    int userSelection;

    do
    {
        userSelection = view.ShowMenu();
        if (userSelection == 1)
        {
            //Add orders

            model.AddOrder(view.AddOrder());                    
        }

        else if (userSelection == 2)
        {
            //Display Orders

            view.DisplayAllOrders(model.GetOrder());
        }
        else if (userSelection == 3)
        {
            //Filter Orders
            model.FilterOrder                   
        }
    }
    while (userSelection != 4);
```

Comment: `DisplayAllOrders(orders.Where(o => o..GetAmount() > Value).ToArray());`

Comment: Even though you have added a lot of code, this barely hides the fact that you didn't even try anything. If you would have added a [mcve], that would be very clear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I can see that you tried to provide as much information as possible with your code, but too much code actually clouds the perception of the problem at hand (like looking for `model.FilterOrder` in 146 lines of code! Please read the link provided by @Sefe and reduce your posted code to the necessary bit. Furthermore the people here expect a certain amount of selfdriven effort to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: I apologize to anyone who has had a troubled time looking at my code, I am new, but I will strive to structure more readable questions in the future.

Comment: No worries, every one has to start at the beginning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oldscool way would be to have a method which loops through your `orders` collection and checks each order whether it satisfies the criterion.

You can start with such a method

```
class OrderManager
{
    public List<Order> GetFilteredOrders(double minValue)
    {
          // make a second collection to collect the orders that will match the criterion
          // loop here through collection
          // check if(orders[i].GetAmout() > minValue)
          // collect them

          // return the collected items
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public void FilterOrder(Order filter)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What numerical value would you like the information to be greater than?");
    double Value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i< orders.Length; i++)
    {
       if(orders.get(i).GetAmount()>Value){
           //print orders.get(i) here
        }

    }

}
```